# Change UIBarButton to Red

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I would like to show the EDIT button in red and not the SAVE button as below

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:(_isEdit)? 
@"Save" : @"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
target:self action:@selector(togleEdit)];

[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Go right ahead, that sounds great. The UIBarButtonItem documentation tells you how to change the color: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: The trouble is to change just the one button not both

Comment: I meant I added `[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];` but it turns all buttons red, not Only Edit button

Comment: So don't do that. Set *this* button's tint color, not *every* button's tint color. And only do it when this is the Edit button.

Comment: Hi Matt, sorry I don't know how to do that, was hoping for any example.. :)

Comment: And I gave you one. But honestly, you couldn't have written that code yourself?

Comment: Do you need someone to write every letter of every line of your code for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = 
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: (_isEdit) ? @"Save" : @"Edit" 
                                     style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target: self 
                                    action: @selector(togleEdit)];
if (!_isEdit)
    [barBtn setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Great, makes the Save button red... not the Edit button..

Comment: Then your `_isEdit` must be backwards!

Comment: You really don't know how to fix this by putting in a "not"? `if (!_isEdit)` will turn it around

Comment: no, under _isEdit naturally you press save. When you tap Edit, it initiates _isEdit

Comment: Okay I put in the "not" for you. Happy?

Comment: Ah sorry! Yes I know. Thanks, didn't realise it applied to this bar button and not in general which it was doing before. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background image of the UIBarButton with the message:

```
setBackgroundImage:forState:style:barMetrics:
```

You can find more about the topic on https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/
in session video: Advanced Appearance Customization on iOS.